# Install cloud9 pre-requisites on ssh workspace

Tags: cloud9-ide

Currently when we make a new developer machine, we install node.js then connect with cloud9 via SSH and it installs the additional things it needs to.

Is there a command I can run at the end of my build script to install the cloud9 pre-requisites earlier? (Just to save waiting for it on first connection.)

Maybe the command on this page:
https://github.com/c9/install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should work:

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/c9/install/master/install.sh | bash
```